# PHP echo out multiple div classes

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to build a blog style site with posts in boxes. I have managed to get the names to echo out from the database but they all appear on top of each other. I would like it so that each name in the database gets its own box. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
<div class="box1">

                <div class="productimage"><img src=""></div>

                <?php

                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                echo '<div class= "prodname">' . $data['name'] . '</div>';
                }


                ?>
                    <div class= "proddesc1st"> Armageddon (Prod. Brandon Thomas)</div>
                    <div class="location"> London, UK - </div>
                    <div class="tags1st"> #Electronic, #Producer </div>


        <div class="bioname">Lil B</div>
        <div class="biopic">Rapper/Producer</div>
        <div class="twitterhandlebox"> @lilbthebasegod</div>
        <div class="followbutton"> Follow </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Place the while loop around <div class='box1'> .. </div>

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this.

```
<?php
  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>
<div class="box1">
  <div class="productimage"><img src=""></div>
  <div class= "prodname"><?php echo $data['name'] ?></div>
  <div class= "proddesc1st"> Armageddon (Prod. Brandon Thomas)</div>
  <div class="location"> London, UK - </div>
  <div class="tags1st"> #Electronic, #Producer </div>
  <div class="bioname">Lil B</div>
  <div class="biopic">Rapper/Producer</div>
  <div class="twitterhandlebox"> @lilbthebasegod</div>
  <div class="followbutton"> Follow </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```